# What key is show after 'Scan addresses for funds' in Copay?

Tags: copay

After importing / restoring with 12 phrase, balance was still 0.00, so as others said I pressed `"Settings" > "Wallet" > "More Options" > "Wallet Addresses" > "Scan addresses for funds"`. Got 3 address, one what I was looking for. Balance is still 0.00, but I could copy a key. Is this key the private key? Or the address of the wallet? How can I get back my money with this key?

Comment: What are the first four letters of the key?

Comment: `1CuU` on screen and `1Bok` copied to clipboard.

Comment: That's not a key, that's just a normal address

Comment: None of the two is good?

Comment: They are both addresses. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I though some private key I will able to see. But not. Thought it might possible to assess amount without Copay, from an outer solution.